# How to exclude some column in Comparison Date Range in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a question. Is it possible to apply Comparison date range in "Chart > Table" chart type not to all columns that I have? I mean that I have for example 5 columns and would like compare only 2 of them to the previous time. When I use Comparison date range feature it double all of my columns. How could I exclude some of them?

Answer (score 1):

If you add a comparison date range to the table, by default you will see the delta change for all metrics (columns). You can de-select 'show compare' checkbox for a particular column in the Style menu of that table.